# Android app blank but not in Designer?

Tags: java, android, alarm

I am making an alarm app but i wanted to change it to be a reminder and basically you type in the reminder and when the alarm goes off you can click to do text to speech on the reminder you saved. However, between testing and adding the text to speech my android app no longer shows any objects when running in the emulator but when designing i can see them all. I have tried to copy all the code into a new project but it does the same.

Here's the image of the emulator and designer.

[image: Yes I know its very basic but its my first app.]

It doesn't say but its a Relative Layout

There is the files of the project.

http://www.mediafire.com/file/uhybhd5sygu2714/AlarmFix.zip

Answer (score 0):

First dont combine Contraintlayout attributes (such as : app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf) it will not works with Relative/LinearLayout, just you need to use attributes such as android:layout_below...  [RelativeLayout.LayoutParams](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvUpdate"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearalarm" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etReminder"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Your Reminder"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:textAlignment="center" />

<TimePicker
    android:id="@+id/timePicker"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/etReminder" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearalarm"
    android:layout_below="@id/timePicker"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/alarm_on"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ALARM ON" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/alarm_off"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ALARM OFF" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnPlayRem"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="PLAY LATEST REMINDER" />

</LinearLayout></RelativeLayout>
```